# How to get a ref to the dom node of a google map's marker in react?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, redux, google-maps-react

Using the google-maps-react npm package I can get a ref to the map's dom node like so:

```
loadMap() {
  
  const maps = this.props.google.maps;
  const mapRef = this.refs.map;       <---- ref set in render function on dom node
  const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(mapRef);  <--- the dom node
  ...
  this.map = new maps.Map(node, mapConfig);
  this.mapRef = mapRef;
}
```

It's pretty easy because mapref is set in the render method:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: mapHeight }} ref="map">
    ...
```

And then that is used to set `node` and then that is used to new up the map.

How would I do this with a map's marker?  A marker doesn't need a dom node to be created and therefore I cant get a ref to the marker.

```
 this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({someOptions});  <----- no dom node needed
```

I want to do this because I need to dynamically change the icon of the marker based on some value in my redux store.  I have tried changing the icon via props (see below), but it somehow prevents the icon marker from being draggable even though draggable is set to true.

```
     return (
      <Marker 
        key={foo} 
        position={latLngPos}
        icon={ active ? activeIcon : defaultIcon }
        draggable={true}
        onDragstart={() => { return this.handleMapMarkerDragStart();}} 
        onDragend={() => { return this.handleMapMarkerDrop();}} 
      />);
```

I suspect things are acting strangely because to get google's maps api to work with react, the components have to deal with the actual dom nodes instead of the virtual dom nodes.

Any insight into this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> I want to do this because I need to dynamically change the icon of the
>   marker based on some value in my redux store. I have tried changing
>   the icon via props (see below), but it somehow prevents the icon
>   marker from being draggable even though draggable is set to true.

the following example demonstrates how to:

- set marker as *draggable*
- set custom icon per marker

Example

```
const handleDragEnd = (props, marker, event) => {
  console.log(event.latLng);
};

const defaultIcon =
  "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/blue-pushpin.png";
const activeIcon =
  "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/pink-pushpin.png";

const MapWrapper = props => {
  return (
    <div className="map-container">
      <Map
        google={props.google}
        className={"map"}
        zoom={4}
        initialCenter={{ lat: -24.9923319, lng: 135.2252427 }}
      >
        {props.places.map((place, i) => {
          const active = i % 2 === 0;
          return (
            <Marker
              icon={active ? activeIcon : defaultIcon}
              key={place.id}
              position={{ lat: place.lat, lng: place.lng }}
              draggable={true}
              onDragend={handleDragEnd}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Map>
    </div>
  );
};
```

> Note: [`Marker` component](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/master/src/components/Marker.js#L6) does not support `onDragstart` event
>   listener at the moment in `google-maps-react` library, but it could be
>   attached directly to Google Maps Marker object

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7ryqw0287)